# Image not showing up when adding it in maketitle

Tags: graphics, titles, logos

I'm trying to modify `\maketitle` to add a logo before the title, but it's not showing.
I'm gessing the because of the `titlepage` option in `\documentclass[titlepage, a4paper, 12pt]{article}` but how to solve it ?

Here is my document :

```
\documentclass[titlepage, a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{CatCatch\\Cahier des charges\\42/2}
\author{John \bsc{Doe} \and Foo \bsc{Bar} \and Someone \bsc{Else}}
\date{19 janvier 2018}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\and}{\\}
\def\@maketitle{
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=120mm]{logo.png}\\[8ex]
        {\Huge \@title }\\[4ex] 
        {\Large \@author}\\[4ex] 
        \@date\\[8ex]
    \end{center}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just remove the `titlepage` option. What's its purpose?

Comment: What's the point of redefining `\maketitle`? What's wrong with `\title{\includegraphics[width=120mm]{logo.png}\\[8ex]
CatCatch\\Cahier des charges\\42/2}` with the original `\maketitle` command?

Comment: the purpose of titlepage is to have the title page separated from the rest of the document

Answer (score 1):

The `report` class defines `\maketitle` in two different ways, according to the presence of the `titlepage` option.

When the option is specified, `\maketitle` will not use `\@maketitle`, but will directly arrange the elements.

When the option is specified, `\maketitle` will delegate some aspects to `\@maketitle`. Use the `titlepage` environment in the redefinition of `\@maketitle`.

So, the correct definition for `\@maketitle` should be

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \begin{titlepage}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=120mm]{logo.png}\\[8ex]
  {\Huge \@title\\[4ex]}% <-- note where the brace is
  {\Large \@author\\[4ex]}% <-- note where the brace is
  \@date
  \end{titlepage}%
}
```

[image]